# Change the first row as the header on Shapelets-query

Tags: python, dataframe, header, widget, visualization

I was trying a couple of example on Shapelets-queries because I wanted to show on Shapelets-platform a table. After importing the data, I saw that my columns name were by default (Column0, Column1, Column2). I tried to change it by using this

data = session.from_csv(""/root/test_10:04:2023/Resources/mitdb102.csv"", header=1)

so I can have the first row as the column name. However, it seems that it doesn’t have this argument, and I got this error:

TypeError: SandBox.from_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'

Can someone help me please?

here is my code:

```
import shapelets as sh
from shapelets.apps import DataApp
app = DataApp(name=""13_table"", description=""table"")
session = sh.sandbox()
data = session.from_csv(""/root/test_10:04:2023/Resources/mitdb102.csv"")
data=data.head()        
print(data.columns)
data = session.from_csv(""/root/test_10:04:2023/Resources/mitdb102.csv"", header=1)
table1 = app.table(data=data )
app.place(table1)

app.register() 




column0         column1    column2
--------------  ---------  ---------
VARCHAR         VARCHAR    VARCHAR
--------------  ---------  ---------
'Elapsed time'  'V5'       'V2'
'seconds'       'mV'       'mV'
0.000           -0.200     0.005
0.003           -0.200     0.005
0.006           -0.200     0.005

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, we do not have this argument at the moment, to do what you were looking for, you need to do it in two steps.
first, you need to rename the columns.
Secondly, you need to keep everything except the first row,
Here is the correct code.

```
import shapelets as sh
from shapelets.apps import DataApp
app = DataApp(name=""13_table"", description=""table"")
session = sh.sandbox()
data = session.from_csv(""/root/test_10:04:2023/Resources/mitdb102.csv"")
data=data.head()
print(data)
data=data.rename_columns({'column0':'Elapsed time', 'column1':'V5', ""column2"": ""V2""})
data=session.from_sql(f""SELECT * FROM {data.alias} OFFSET 1"")
print(data)
table1 = app.table(data=data )
app.place(table1)
app.register()
```

you can look at your documentation https://shapelets.io/doc/ https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo
Thank you for helping us to improve our product!